# Generic EF6 Repository Method Doesn't Generate Correct SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this method in my repository exposing EF6 DbContext.

```
public IList<T> GetEntities<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
{
    return db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList<T>();
}
```

When I watch this method execute in SQL Profiler, the predicate is executed in memory. The SQL statement contains no where clause.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate should be an `Expression` so that Entity Framework can actually use it to generate SQL instead of just executing it. If you pass in a `Func` you are actually calling the [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public IList<T> GetEntities<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    return db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList<T>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

`.Where` accepts one of two things, either `Func<T, bool>` or `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. If you pass in `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, then your EF query should work properly.

```
public IList<T> GetEntities<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
```

You'd call it the same way:

```
GetEntities(x => x.Id == 34)
```

When you pass in `Func<T, bool>`, the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation executes, which uses Linq-to-Objects rather than Linq-to-Entities.